# CSS3 rotate3d Inaccuracies

Tags: jquery, html, math, css

Does anyone know of a solution to the inaccuracies produced by the css3 transform attribute: `rotate3d` (or `rotateX`, `rotateY`, `rotateZ`)?

The function computes an elements position by applying the rotation angle to the matrix `[cos(angle) sin(angle) -sin(angle) cos(angle) someOtherTrigForZ(angle) someOtherTrigForZ(angle)]`..

I am creating a cube using these css3 attributes, and if you inspect the `id=cube` element in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gE3FL/) (after rotating the cube a few times using arrow keys)(look in computed styles), you can see that the rotate3d matrix does not apply any kind of number fixing (some sort of rounding method) to computed styles.

```
-webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.04943792709533707, -0.6982520256787774, 0, 0, 0.6982520256787774, 0.04943792709533707, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

The result I am getting is poorly drawn elements that do not line up; this is visible to the naked eye if you look at the borders on the cube's faces.

Does anyone know of a way to smooth out/round the trigonometry calculations so that my borders aren't choppy?

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about… The edges line up perfectly, as far as I can tell. I spun the cube every which way for a few minutes and can't see a discernible misalignment (and I'm pretty picky about these things). Tested in current Safari (Version 6.0.2 (8536.26.17)), and a fairly recent WebKit nightly with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

In the jsfiddle you linked to, the css class for the cube faces has the border set as `border:1px solid black;` This is actually adding and extra pixel on each edge of a face. That's an extra 2px added to both the width and height. I think this is causing the misalignment. If you add the css property `-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;` to the face class, the misalignment should be corrected.